# How to signal to RSpec that an expectation has failed for a custom Serverspec resource type

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3, serverspec

I have written the serverspec resource type below for checking if keys have the right values for some YAML configuration files I have
For each key in the hash table I assign an attribute on the resource type instance. If a key does not exist I'd like to fail with the appropriate message.
After digging up in rspec's code I found that if I mixin the `RSpec::Expectations` module I can call `fail_with()` which should report that the test fails.
However I'm getting a `SystemStackError` from the line that calls `fail_with()` that says "stack level too deep". I'm guessing that I'm doing it wrong. Is there a way to make the test fail with a message that makes sense?

```
require 'yaml'

module Serverspec
  module Type

    class YAMLFile < Base
      include RSpec::Expectations

      def initialize(path)
        yaml = YAML.load_file(path)
        return unless yaml

        yaml.each { |key, value| self.send('#{key}=', value) }
      end

      def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
        # fail here with message
        self.fail_with('The key does not exist in the YAML file')
      end
    end

    def yaml_file(path)
      YAMLFile.new(path)
    end
  end
end

include Serverspec::Type
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the `fail()` method instead of `fail_with()`.
I still don't know why I can't use `fail_with()` though.
Here's the working code for future reference:

```
require 'yaml'

module Serverspec
  module Type

    class YAMLFile < Base
      def initialize(path)
        yaml = YAML.load_file(path)
        return unless yaml

        yaml.each { |key, value| self.send('#{key}=', value) }
      end

      def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
        fail "The key '%s' does not exist in the YAML document" % m
      end
    end

    def yaml_file(path)
      YAMLFile.new(path)
    end
  end
end

include Serverspec::Type
```